# How to notify when any DataRow elements change?

Tags: c#, datatable

Currently the way the system is set up, I execute a PropertChanged event when SelectedRow changes

```
PropertyChanged += Table_PropertyChanged;

private void Table_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the Selected row changes..
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedRow))
    {
     //some code here 
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that if it's the bottom row in a table, nothing updates because no new line was selected. I'd like to check to see if any individual elements of the row changes.

Currently the user interacts with a DataView which is bound to the table 'tbl' behind the scenes. That DataView is called 'dv'.

The only way i've found to correctly fire an event when the user edits a field in one of the rows is as follows

```
public TableViewModel()
{
    PropertyChanged += Table_PropertyChanged;
    // Prepare the Dummy DataTable, put it in the main Tbl DataTable
    ValsToDummy();

    Tbl = Dummy;

    Tbl.TableName = "Dummy";
    dv.Table = Tbl;

    dv.ListChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventHandler(OnListChanged);
}

protected void OnListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ListChangedType.ToString() == "ItemChanged")
    {
    Console.WriteLine("ListChanged:");
    Console.WriteLine("\t    Type = " + args.ListChangedType);
    Console.WriteLine("\tOldIndex = " + args.OldIndex);
    Console.WriteLine("\tNewIndex = " + args.NewIndex);
    Console.out.writeline("change");
    updateTable();
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it fire too easily and too often resulting in a stack overflow. UpdateTable calls the query to update my database. The console output looks like this.. repeating many many times until crash

```
ListChanged:
        Type = ItemChanged
    OldIndex = -1
    NewIndex = 9
ListChanged:
        Type = ItemChanged
    OldIndex = -1
    NewIndex = 9
ListChanged:
        Type = ItemChanged
    OldIndex = -1
    NewIndex = 9
ListChanged:
        Type = ItemChanged
    OldIndex = -1
    NewIndex = 9
ListChanged:
        Type = ItemChanged
    OldIndex = -1
    NewIndex = 9
```

My current workaround is

```
 if (args.ListChangedType.ToString() == "ItemChanged" && args.OldIndex == args.NewIndex)
```

Comment: I'm about to leave work but I will check in on your progress and offer assistance where I can. Could you please detail what you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do your events fire and the associated methods get called?

Comment: I'll post a more verbose description.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is going to work like your other event, you need to create an event handler for your data table's ColumnChanged event and write a method that will handle the change.

```
    DataTable yourTable = new DataTable();

    //This is the important step
    // add a ColumnChanged event handler for the table.
    yourTable.ColumnChanged += new 
        DataColumnChangeEventHandler(Column_Changed );
```

**See Also**
[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the edit. The See Also was a nice touch.